# Creating unmanaged object in C#

Tags: c#, c++, .net, dll, c++-cli

I want to create an instance of unmanaged c++ class.
I have this c++ interface:

```
// ITestDll.h
#pragma once

class ITestDll {
public:
    virtual void PrintHello() = 0;
};
```

Unmanaged DLL code:

```
// TestDll.h
#pragma once

#ifdef TestDll_EXPORTS  
#define TestDll_API __declspec(dllexport)   
#else  
#define TestDll_API __declspec(dllimport)   
#endif 

#include <string>
#include "ITestDll.h"

class TestDll : public ITestDll {
public:
    TestDll();
    void PrintHello();
};

extern "C" TestDll_API ITestDll* CreateTestClass() {
    return new TestDll();
}
///////////////////////////////////////////////
// TestDLL.cpp
#include "stdafx.h"

#define TestDll_EXPORTS
#include "TestDll.h"
#include <iostream>

TestDll::TestDll() {
//
}

void TestDll::PrintHello() {
    std::cout << "Hello, world!" << std::endl;
}
```

C++/CLR Wrapper:

```
// TestCLR.h
#pragma once

#include "ITestDll.h"

namespace Test {

public ref class TestCLR
{
public:
    TestCLR();
    void PrintHello();
private:
    ITestDll* obj;
};
}
/////////////////////////////////////////
// TestCLR.cpp
#include "TestCLRDll.h"
#include <windows.h>
namespace Test {
TestCLR::TestCLR() {
    HINSTANCE testDll = LoadLibraryA("testDll.dll");
    typedef ITestDll* (*TestDllCtor)();
    TestDllCtor ctor = (TestDllCtor) GetProcAddress(testDll, "CreateTestClass");
    this->obj = ctor();
}


void TestCLR::PrintHello() {
    obj->PrintHello();
}
}
```

C# application:

```
using TestCLR;

namespace TestUnmanagedCLR
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TestCLR inst = new TestCLR();

            inst.PrintHello();
        }
    }
}
```

I've enabled an unmanaged debugging. I'm getting an error in CLR wrapper at this line: this->obj = ctor();
The error is:
Managed Debugging Assistant 'FatalExecutionEngineError' has detected a problem in 'C:...\TestUnmanagedCLR\bin\Debug\TestUnmanagedCLR.exe'.

Additional information: The runtime has encountered a fatal error. The address of the error was at 0x70204cc0, on thread 0x1ce8. The error code is 0xc0000005. This error may be a bug in the CLR or in the unsafe or non-verifiable portions of user code. Common sources of this bug include user marshaling errors for COM-interop or PInvoke, which may corrupt the stack.

Any suggestions, why does this happen? What I'm doing wrong? Calling dll from c++ clr works well, but from c# this does not work.

UPDATE:
The problem was that a .net application did not find an unmanaged dll, so putting it into project's folder solves the issue. (procmon rules:)